# How to get a subtree given a path from a tree object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tree object of the form:

```
var data = [{
    "root": true,
    "label": null,
    "question": "What product category?",
    "nodes": [{
        "label": "Clothes",
        "question": "What type of clothing?",
        "nodes": [{
            "label": "Jeans",
            "question": "Color of jeans?",
            "nodes": [{
                    "label": "Blue",
                    "question": null,
                    "nodes": null
                },

            ]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I am trying to return the subtree given a path of array [0,0,0] which would return `data[0].nodes[0].nodes[0]`. I am trying out an iterative approach would it be possible to do it in a recursive approach?

Comment: What is (0:0:0)? A string? With the parentheses included? Please provide he code you have tried with.

Comment: Updated the question, it is initially a string converted to an array.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to close all your nested arrays with `]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is recursive function:

```js
function subTree(arr, indexes) {
    var a = arr[indexes[0]];
    return indexes.length > 1 ? subTree(a.nodes, indexes.slice(1)) : a;
}

var data = [{
    "root": true,
    "label": null,
    "question": "What product category?",
    "nodes": [{
        "label": "Clothes",
        "question": "What type of clothing?",
        "nodes": [{
            "label": "Jeans",
            "question": "Color of jeans?",
            "nodes": [{
                "label": "Blue",
                "question": null,
                "nodes": null
              }]  
        }]
    }]
}];

console.log(subTree(data, [0,0,0]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### The thought process to arrive at this solution

As you asked the question in comments, here is the process I went through when addressing this question:

First thing I thought: I probably need to go through the object properties to find the one that has children.

Second thing: No, I don't -- it is always the `nodes` property.

Then: but wait -- the first index is not taken from a `nodes` property, while all other indexes are. Is this a problem for getting at a generic solution?

Then, I realised it is not, since the first call starts with an array -- I don't need to know whether it is an array that was given as the value of a `nodes` property or was just the initial data array. An array is an array. Only at the moment of the first recursive call (and all deeper ones) will I need to mention the `nodes` property by name, and it will always be that property name.

It seemed logical that at each recursion you would pass the array of the `nodes` property *and* the array of remaining indices, so without the index that was already processed. That latter array will reduce to an empty array, which will be the end-point of the recursion.

Then I started to write the code to deal with the end-of-recursion case, i.e. where you are out of indexes. First I thought to write

```
function subTree(arr, indexes) {
    if (!indexes.length) return arr;
    // ...
}
```

But that isn't right, since the return value should not be an array, but the object having that array -- so in fact this code would have recursed too deep!

So the second attempt became:

```
function subTree(arr, indexes) {
    var index = indexes.shift();
    if (indexes.length == 0) return arr[index];
    // ...
}
```

The `shift` call seemed a nice way to remove the first index and keep it in a separate variable, so it could be used for returning the right object.

This looked fine: if the call was `subTree(data, [0])` I would indeed get the desired result.

Then I continued to write the recursion case:

```
function subTree(arr, indexes) {
    var index = indexes.shift();
    if (indexes.length == 0) return arr[index];
    return subTree(arr[index].nodes, indexes);
}
```

This looked fine also. It worked.

But seeing two `return` statements, which are just separated by an `if`, calls for a ternary operator, so I changed it to:

```
function subTree(arr, indexes) {
    var index = indexes.shift();
    return indexes.length ? subTree(arr[index].nodes, indexes) : arr[index];
}
```

I posted this, and then realised it was not such a good idea to use `shift`: it modifies the argument passed to the function, which is not very nice towards the caller: it is an unexpected side-effect. So I should create new instances of arrays, instead of modifying the given indexes array:

```
function subTree(arr, indexes) {
    var index = indexes[0];
    return indexes.length > 1 ? subTree(arr[index].nodes, indexes.slice(1)) : arr[index];
}
```

`slice` is a method to take a shallow copy of a part of a given array, so with the `1` as only argument a new array is created which just does not have the first index any more. With this way of working the condition had of course to change from a simple `indexes.length` to `indexes.length > 1`.

Finally, I felt a bit stupid I had created a variable `index` avoiding the repetitive `[0]`, but had not avoided using `arr[index]` twice. So then the final solution came to the surface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I had in mind. it's been a while since I wrote a recursive function  :). can you give me some insight into the thought process that led you to this solution very quickly?

Comment: I added a description of my thought process to the answer ;-)

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you so much.