# Accessing nested arrays with dynamic depth via indices

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nested

I'm fairly new to typescript and I have some issues to access an object in array with dynamic depth.
For example:

```
export interface folder{
 name: string,
 type: string,
 position: number[], // index for each depth level
 children: folder[]
```

```
{
  "name": "Folder1",
  "depth": 0,
  "position": [0] // indeces for each depth level
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Folder2",
      "depth": 1,
      "position": [0,0] // indeces for each depth level
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Folder3"
          "depth": 2,
          "position": [0,0,0] // indeces for each depth level
        },
        {
          "name": "Folder4"
          "depth": 2,
          "position": [0,0,1] // indeces for each depth level
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To get Folder4 I'd use the dot notation like:
`this.folder[0].children[0].children[1]`

Now I was wondering, if there is a way to dynamicly access the object via the position array without iterating over the whole structure. I managed to get it working by defining a string and adding `".children[PositionIndex]"` for each value in position and executing it with `eval`. However that is obviously not a reasonable/safe way to do this.

Any help would be greatly apprecieated.Thanks!

Comment: You cannot access your "folder4" via it's own "position" field without digging into the structure. The reason is simple: To retrieve the "position" field, you first need to dig into the structure to get access to it. However, if you are deep enough to have access to the values of the field, you are already at the right depth. In other words, you need to be at the final depth to have access to a field that describes how to reach the final depth. To be honest, IMHO your "position" fields are (in that context) useless (may be useful for other tasks).

Comment: I would add that the `depth` is also not very useful: it is redundant information. You seem to be saying that you find  `this.folder[0].children[0].children[1]` too verbose? Then make a function that takes a list of indices (like [0, 0, 1]) and performs this lookup. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284139/how-to-get-a-subtree-given-a-path-from-a-tree-object/42284365#42284365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a "position" field that describes the path to a certain depth/folder nested deeply into the structure itself, have a second, shallow structure that maps folder names to depths and use it to reach a folder:

```js
const folders = {
  "name": "Folder1",
  "depth": 0,
  "position": [0], // note: this is wrong, folder one isn't nested and therefor has a position of []
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Folder2",
      "depth": 1,
      "position": [0,0],
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Folder3",
          "depth": 2,
          "position": [0,0,0]
        },
        {
          "name": "Folder4",
          "depth": 2,
          "position": [0,0,1]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const folderDepths = {
  // this maps depths to folders. note that "folder1" does not have a
  // depth, because it is the root node and is not nested. this means
  // that all nodes nested below folder1 have one path segment less
  // compared to your original structure.
  Folder1: [],
  Folder2: [0],
  Folder3: [0, 0],
  Folder4: [0, 1]
};

const accessFolder = (name, depths, tree) => {
  // we use this function to access (sub-)folders. it takes the name
  // of the folder to reach, the depths-mapping and the original
  // structure. stops when there are no more children to dig into or
  // the final depth is reached. returns the accessed (sub-)tree.
  let retv = tree;
  let path = depths[name];
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length && retv; i += 1) {
    if (retv.children && retv.children[path[i]]) {
      retv = retv.children[path[i]];
    }
  }
  return retv;
}



console.log(accessFolder('Folder2', folderDepths, folders));
console.log(accessFolder('Folder4', folderDepths, folders));
```